# How do you set Stripe publishable_key in your rspec tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, stripe-payments

I have a controller test that I am working on. The method creates a `Strip::Recipient` object, but I plan on stubbing it. The issue I am running into is that I keep getting the message:

```
No stripe.com publishable key found. Please set config.stripe.publishable_key in config/application.rb to one of your publishable keys, which can be found here: https://manage.stripe.com/#account/apikeys
```

spec:

```
let!(:courier)      { FactoryGirl.create(:confirmed_courier) }

it "redirects to bank info page" do
  stripe_recipient = Stripe::Recipient.create(
    :name => "#{courier.name} #{courier.name}",
    :type => 'individual',
    :description => "User ID 1 (test), employee",
    :email => courier.email
  )

  allow_any_instance_of(Courier).to receive(:retrieve_or_create_stripe_recipient).and_return(stripe_recipient)

  get :bank_info, {id: courier.id}
  expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
end
```

I have tried setting the `api_key` (`Stripe.api_key = ENV['STRIPE_API_KEY']`). I have also tried setting the `publishable_key` in a similar fashion, but no such method exists.

How do you set up Stripe for your controller tests?

Thanks!

Comment: You can just duplicate development environment variables to test. Maybe i didn't understand something. What is your `config/initializers/stripe.rb` file, or where you store stripe variables.

Comment: @zishe You were right.